# Visual Studio 2013 complains on neutral culture

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, migration, culture

After having migrated a C# solution from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2013 I am stuck with the following problem: One of the migrated projects fails to rebuild with the following error as an excuse:

```
Invalid argument. Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
Neutral is an invalid culture identifier.
```

This error is presented without any specifics about the exact part of the code that causes it, except the project name.

I have found and replaced all the occurrences of `Culture=neutral` with `Culture=en-US` but this was of no help. The error remains. What can be its cause?

Comment: Can you share the code that is causing the error?

Comment: I would share the part of code that causes the error, but I don't know which part it is. I will try to divide and conquer to determine.